# Can't get a complicated mysql query to work

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write a mysql query and I'm having some issues with it.  I'm trying to query WooCommerce data out of my Wordpress database.  Basic invoice data is stored in the wp_posts table and the rest of the data is stored in the wp_postmeta table.  Now 1 inovice in the wp_posts table points to multiple items in the wp_postmeta table.  Here is an example.

WP_POSTS

```
----------------------------------------------------
ID           STATUS                 Date
----------------------------------------------------
0001         OPEN                   01/01/2000
0002         OPEN                   01/01/2000
0003         CLOSED                 01/02/2000
```

WP_POSTMETA

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID        POST_ID               META_KEY                META_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001      0001                  CustomerLN              Test
0002      0001                  CustomerFN              Tester
0003      0001                  Payment_Type            PayPal
0004      0001                  Invoice_Total           $200
0005      0002                  CustomerLN              Doe
0006      0002                  CustomerFN              John
0007      0002                  Payment_Type            CC-Mastercard
0008      0002                  Invoice_Total           $1000
```

I've got a basic query that pulls the data in from the wp_posts table but I can't figure out how to pull data from the second table based on the META_KEY value.

Any help would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the **[Entity-Attribute-Value](https://perfectsmoked.com/best-gas-smoker/)** world.

To have a normal representation of the resultset you might need not only `JOIN` these two tables but also `PIVOT` the resultset. You can do that with a query like

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'CustomerLN'    
                THEN m.meta_value END) customer_last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'CustomerFN'    
                THEN m.meta_value END) customer_firt_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'Payment_Type'  
                THEN m.meta_value END) payment_type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'Invoice_Total' 
                THEN m.meta_value END) invoice_total
 FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m
   ON p.id = m.post_id
 GROUP BY p.id, p.status
```

Sample output:

```
+------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------+
| id   | status | customer_last_name | customer_firt_name | payment_type  | invoice_total |
+------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------+
|    1 | OPEN   | Test               | Tester             | PayPal        | $200          |
|    2 | OPEN   | Doe                | John               | CC-Mastercard | $1000         |
|    3 | CLOSED | NULL               | NULL               | NULL          | NULL          |
+------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba9fc/2)** demo

---

Now to be able to filter your records based on meta keys and meta values you'll have to use `HAVING` clause

For example if you want to get invoices made by customer Jhon Doe

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'CustomerLN'    
                THEN m.meta_value END) customer_last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'CustomerFN'    
                THEN m.meta_value END) customer_first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'Payment_Type'  
                THEN m.meta_value END) payment_type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'Invoice_Total' 
                THEN m.meta_value END) invoice_total
 FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m
   ON p.id = m.post_id
 GROUP BY p.id, p.status
HAVING customer_last_name = 'Doe'
   AND customer_first_name = 'John'
```

Output:

```
+------+--------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
| id   | status | customer_last_name | customer_first_name | payment_type  | invoice_total |
+------+--------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
|    2 | OPEN   | Doe                | John                | CC-Mastercard | $1000         |
+------+--------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba9fc/7)** demo

Comment: I do have one last queston.  I added a date to my query.  When I display it I'm trying to run the date_format on the result.  This is what I have.  $sale refers the current line of data being echo'd to the screen.  date_format($sale->post_date, '%M %D %Y) .  What am I doing wrong?   The date is echoing out on it's own in the following format:  '2012-08-08 18:29:02'.

Comment: @maddtechwf You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help :) And good luck (I mean it). EAV models could be tough to maintain and query against.

Comment: @maddtechwf Sorry I didn't quite understand your follow up question. DO you want to format date in sql query or on client side with php?

Comment: @maddtechwf I believe your format string is invalid. Take a look at an example I made on [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HVNpNL). I guess you mixing MySQL and php format strings. It's in MySQL you use `%` character in php you don't.

Comment: I looked at your code and did the following.  Before I displayed the date I loaded it into $date and then I called date in the appropriate td and used the format.  When I used the format, I got the following error.  Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: @maddtechwf did you created `$date` as `new DateTime(...)`? Probably not.

Answer (score 2):

To start, I would do

```
select a.*, b.* from WP_POSTS a, wp_postmeta b
where b.POST_ID = a.id
```

What have you done?

Answer (score 2):

For this circumstance you want to use a "JOIN".  Check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp, which is almost exactly what you want to do.

It'll end something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.PostId;
```

Also note that your table name is wrong for the second table.

Comment: Yeah I saw that after I posted it.  Lets say that there are like 20 different entries in the postmeta for each invoice.  How can I pull specific values based on specific keys?

I just need 4 specific values from the postmeta table for each invoice.  I'm wanting to show the First & Last name,payment type, and total.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not attempt to JOIN both tables, because their table structures are dissimilar.  Let us create a view that consumes `WP_POSTMETA`'s data, consolidating it.

Joining `WP_POSTMETA` with itself X-1 times for every X fields you are interested in produces 0 to X lines for every `Post_ID`.   Use the `WHERE` clause to get 1 column from each copy of the table and reduce the total amount of lines per `Post_ID` to 1 (or none).

Filter out the rubbish and voilà!

NOTE:  `[table_name2]` can be called `temp0`,  `[table_name3]` called `temp1`, `[table_name4]` called `temp2`, or whatever you wish.

```
SELECT WP_POSTMETA.Post_ID AS Post_ID, WP_POSTMETA.CustomerLN AS CustomerLN, [table_name2].CustomerFN AS  CustomerFN, [table_name3].Payment_Type AS Payment_Type, [table_name4].Meta_Value AS  Invoice_Total 
FROM WP_POSTMETA 
JOIN WP_POSTMETA AS [table_name2] ON WP_POSTMETA.Post_ID = [table_name2].Post_ID 
JOIN WP_POSTMETA AS [table_name3] ON WP_POSTMETA.Post_ID = [table_name3].Post_ID 
JOIN WP_POSTMETA AS [table_name4] ON WP_POSTMETA.Post_ID = [table_name4].Post_ID 
WHERE WP_POSTMETA.Meta_Value =  "CustomerLN"
AND [table_name2].Meta_Value =  "CustomerFN"
AND [table_name3].Meta_Value =  "Payment_Type"
AND [table_name4].Meta_Value =  "Invoice_Total"
```

This will generate an output that can be made into a `view` by prepending

```
CREATE VIEW WP_TRANSACTIONS AS
```

and  this view `JOIN`ed to WP_POST

```
SELECT * FROM WP_POST 
LEFT JOIN WP_TRANSACTIONS ON WP_POST.Post_ID = WP_TRANSACTIONS.Post_ID
```