# Wordpress MySQL query with WHERE clause after GROUP_CONCAT returns unexpected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, group-concat

```
            SELECT p.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_key ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR '||') as meta_keys, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_value ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR '||') as meta_values
        FROM $wpdb->posts p 
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm on pm.post_id = p.ID 
        WHERE p.post_type = 'item' and p.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND pm.meta_key = 'adtype' 
        AND pm.meta_value = '1'
        GROUP BY p.ID
        ORDER BY p.post_date_gmt DESC
        LIMIT 0,10
```

I'm using a special WordPress query to get post and postmeta data and ran into a problem when I wanted to add an additional WHERE on the postmeta.

Here I want to limit results where pm.meta_key adtype is equal to 1. The query works, but var_dump() shows that it changes the value of the group concatenated meta_keys and meta_values.

In my results I no longer get meta_keys and meta_values out as concatenated results, rather they get set to the WHERE values of 'adtype' and '1' respectively.

The query works without the additional WHERE clauses, but I would like the ability to filter results.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, when you add the `WHERE` clause :

```
    AND pm.meta_key = 'adtype' 
    AND pm.meta_value = '1'
```

you are limiting the result to only the rows that have these values, so in your meta_keys & meta_values your won't have values that differ from those specified in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Okay.. So when I group_concat on these WHERE clauses, the only values set are adtype and 1. That makes sense, but now how can I filter these results?

Comment: You want to filter by which field ?

Comment: You want to filter on `adtype` and you want in your `meta_keys` all the values (not only adtype) ?

Comment: Yea.. I'm so close to doing what I want with this query, but as you mentioned the way I'm trying to get the data isn't working. It would be much simpler if the data were all in one table. :/

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow use the result of max(case when pm.meta_key='adtype' then pm.meta_value end) in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself in this thread: [Can't get a complicated mysql query to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564863/cant-get-a-complicated-mysql-query-to-work)

In the SELECT statement I gave a new value for adtype with:

max(case when pm.meta_key='adtype' then pm.meta_value end) as adtype

And after GROUP BY I added:

HAVING adtype = '1'

This worked!